# Sijax and Flask URL redirect

Tags: python, flask, sijax

I'm trying to make a login form using a little ajax. When the user fills in a wrong password/username combination the error message gets added to the page with sijax:

These are my two methods:
1) The Sijax method

```
@staticmethod
def login(obj_response, uname, password):
    # Verify the user.
    username = uname.strip()
    password = password.strip()
    user = User.query.filter_by(username = username).first()

    if user is None:
        error = 'Invalid username/password combination'
    elif password != user.password:
        error = 'Invalid username/password combination'

    # Log the user in if the info is correct.
    else:
        login_user(user)
        session['logged_in'] = True 
        obj_response.redirect(url_for('user_home'))

    # Clear the previous error message.
    obj_response.script("$('#errormessage').remove();")

    # Add an error message to the html if there is an error.
    obj_response.html_append(".loginform", "<h4 id='errormessage'>" + error + "</h4>")
```

2) The python method:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if g.sijax.is_sijax_request:
    # The request looks like a valid Sijax request
    # Let's register the handlers and tell Sijax to process it
    g.sijax.register_object(SijaxHandler)
    return g.sijax.process_request()

return render_template('login.html')
```

What I'm trying to do know is check if the username/password combination is correct and if it's not display the error message using ajax but if it is, redirect the user to his home page (url_for('userhome')).

I'm trying it know with the sijax method:obj_response.redirect(url_for('user_home')) but this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

I get this error:
obj_response.html_append(".loginform", "" + error + "")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'error' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you always use `error` but only define it in case of an error.

Simple solution: Add `error = None` right before the `if user is None:` line. Besides that, only create the error message element in case there's an error:

```
if error:
    obj_response.html_append(".loginform", "<h4 id='errormessage'>" + error + "</h4>")
```